# How to assign the parameter list "$@" to another variable?

Tags: bash, shell, parameters

In a shell script I want a variable `p` to be equal to `"$@"`, so that the following two lines of code produce the same result:

```
for x in "$p"; do echo $x; done
for x in "$@"; do echo $x; done
```

If I do `p=$@` or `p="$@"` this doesn't work. 
When the command line arguments have spaces in their names, I can't find a simple workaround to this problem (the combination `p="$@"` and `for x in $p` (quotes removed around $p) works when there are no spaces).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`"$@"` is special in that it even though it is a single quoted expression it expands to zero or more “words”. You can not accomplish the same thing with a normal parameter, but (using a slightly different syntax) it can be done with an array variable/parameter (e.g. in *bash*, *ksh*, *zsh*):

```
array_var=("$@")
for x in "${array_var[@]}"; do printf '<<%s>>\n' "$x"; done
```

Comment: @sivann: The above code will only print something if some positional parameters are already established (e.g. save the code to a file and run it with extra arguments: `bash /path/to/file arg1 'arg2 has spaces'`). Without some more details, it is difficult to tell what problems you are encountering. You may want to ask a new question with more details about what you are trying to do (and what you have already tried).